# What is the name of the phrase that 'repeats' the preceding noun?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> I, Motes, don't know this.

"Motes" is? I think it starts with an 'A'.

Comment: Hmm, tough one. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a noun in apposition. It is used postpositionally.

Comment: And it's not a dependent clause. Clauses are sentences, with verbs and all that stuff. It's just an appositive noun phrase.